# Checkbox state resets on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to get the **"true"** or **"false"** of all checkboxes in a gridview after a button click.
But none of the checkbox is returning **"true"** even if i check them.
Please write me the reason and solution.Thanks in Advance

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                Boolean b = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[r.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("cbox")).Checked;
                Response.Write(b);
            }
        }
```

Comment: well how are you binding it, maybe you bind it again on the button click in case its not in a IsPostBack clause @ pageload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are Rebinding the data on page load (which happens before control events).

Try wrapping your binding methods in

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Load  Data
}
```

EDIT:

Useful link is useful:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events